Rio Terminal - Open new tab in same directory as previous tab
I started to use the rio terminal, and I would like to ask any rio advanced user if they know how to configure the terminal so that when I open a new tab, this tab opens automatically on the same folder as the previous tab. I found in the config file (config.toml) the variable working-dir, described as "Startup directory", but it lets to use a hardcoded folder:
Startup directory
#
# Directory the shell is started in. If this is unset the working
# directory of the parent process will be used.
#
# This configuration only has effect if use-fork is disabled.
#
# Example:
# working-dir = "/Users/raphael/Documents/"

The previous snippet was directly extracted from the file. My question is how I can obtain the folder of the previous tab?. Can I assign an environment variable to a toml file? Is there any way in Zsh to detect the previous tab's current folder?

to open a new tab using same previous path you need adjust your configuration file.
use-current-path - Use same path whenever a new tab is created (Note: requires use-fork to be set to false). 

Like it:
[navigation]
use-current-path = true
use-fork = false

You can check more infos here: https://raphamorim.io/rio/docs/config/navigation/
